# Is it possible to load an object, it transient state from the get go?

Tags: java, hibernate

When querying for a object by id or returning a list of objects using Hibernate, is it possible to tell hibernate to retrieve the object(s) in transient state.

I don't want to track any changes at all, this is a read only type query and speed is of essence.

Comment: -1 - try proof reading your questions.  This is unintelligible.

Comment: GregS so I am getting downvoted because it is me? that's the community spirit.

Comment: @mrblah, are **you** really lecturing about community spirit?  As of this moment, you've asked 703 questions and answered **zero**. As many, many of us have noticed *and pointed out to you*, you frequently ask questions without even making the most cursory attempt to find the answer yourself using the common, well-known resources available to you (like Javadocs or manuals).  You very well might be the most abusive member of this community's goodwill -- it's shocking to a group of us at this point that people are still willing to waste time answering your questions.

Comment: delfuego, I agree with any critism regarding asking questions a little more clearly, and/or following up on others questions etc. BUT, as far as me asking questions, I see nothing wrong with that.  I accept answers, and that is what this site is all about.  If questions were limited to those not already answered on the web, this site sure has ALLOT of moderating to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

`setReadOnly(Object, boolean)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Stateless Session](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html)